# Moved Github repo to another account, but can't push to main

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, push

I've had a Github account setup with my student email at my university, but since my account is going to disappear in a few months, **I moved one of my repositories over to a different**, more permanent **email**. I used Github's built-in repo-copying mechanism to do so and then proceeded to clone it to a different folder on my personal machine. I can make edits and commit them, but **as soon as I hit push I get [this error in VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPyEW.png)**. *"You don't have permissions to push to my-user/my-account."* And it asks me to make a fork.

I am logged into my Github account that is associated with my non-school email on my web browser and in VSCode. I've restarted VSCode a few times and recloned the repo while signed in, but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: check `git config --global --list` and `git config --local --list` make sure your accounts are lined up and also the remotes are updated

Comment: Thanks, I updated those and refreshed the remote but the error persists.

Comment: You're probably pushing with a personal access token, right? And you computer probably has cached credentials to push to GitHub (where that's saved depends on your OS and some other details). You may need to invalidate your credentials cache. Under most workflow, the push and pull operations send credentials at each operation from your cache, rather than whatever you might be logged in as.